# ruby title case problems

Tags: ruby

A course on ruby asks to write a `Title` class, which is initialized with a string. It has one method `fix`, which should return a title-cased version of the string. Here is what I have for my code.

```
class Title
 attr_reader :string

def initialize(string)
 @string = string
end

def fix
 not_capitalized = %w{a and the of}
 word_array = string.downcase.split(" ")
 title_array = []

 word_array.each_with_index do |word, index|
   if index == 0 || !not_captialized.include?(word)
    title_array << word.capitalize
   else
    title_array << word
   end
 end

 title_array.join(" ")
 end
end
```

I keep getting a NameError undefined local variable or method `not_captialized'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your variables.

The first one is `not_capitalized`

The second one is `not_captialized`

Just rename the second one and it should work

i.e. `if index == 0 || !not_capitalized.include?(word)`

Comment: Hey I just want to tell you thanks a lot you really helped me out!!

Answer (score -1):

Just as the error message says. You never defined a local variable or method `not_captialized`, but are trying to use it.